# How can I found all db table records within radius JSON field in PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude, radius

I have table polygon_versions with geo_json field of type json.

DB fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/mzsp-4tg

How can I select all table polygon_versions records within radius of 20 kilometers from geometry point with exact combination of latitude / longtitude?

For example latitude is: 30.502390312011734 and longtitude is: 50.4947950787348

What SQL query I can execute in PostGIS database?

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM polygon_versions WHERE geo_json LIKE '%30.502390312011734%'
```

but it gives me the following error message:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown
LINE 19: SELECT * FROM polygon_versions WHERE geo_json LIKE '%30.5023...
```

Comment: If the data is in a JSON field, it's not yet in PostGIS. Please [Edit] the Question to place the actual SQL you have attempted in the body, not just a link.

Comment: Have a look at https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html

Comment: Thank you, @TomazicM it looks useful, but it did not help to solve my task completely. I'm steel investigating on it

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by "select all table polygon_versions records within radius of 20 kilometers from geometry point". How much of the polygon has to be within radius?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution. SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM polygon_versions WHERE  geo_json::jsonb @> '{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[30.502390312011734,50.4947950787348]]]}}'
```